# Kubuntu X11 focus follows mouse Firefox doesn't play nicely

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, xorg, focus

I started using Unix (Solaris) in the mid '90s and, as a researcher, I found the focus follows mouse without bringing the window I was typing in fantastic for making notes while reading papers.

in the latest iteration 23.04 I've found Firefox will not come forward even when I click on the window edges.

any thoughts?   for the time being I'm using Chrome which works fine.
I haven't found any other weird behaviour along this line.

AMD Ryzen 9, Aorus mobo,  MSI Radeon 4GB video card, 64GB real storage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on GNOME? If so, install https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks. In Tweaks > Windows > Focusing > "Focus on Hover" (or "Secondary-Click").

(I'm not on Ubuntu -I'm on Manjaro, where the package for Tweaks is called "gnome-tweaks".) This has worked in Tweaks both before and since GNOME 45.